# python separate text into different column with comma

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm pulling data from a database and writing to a new Excel file for a report.  My issue is that the last column of data has data that is separated by commas and needs to be separated into separate columns.

As an example I have data like the following:

```
Name  Info
Mike  "a, b, c, d"
Joe  "a, f, z"
```

I need to break these letters out into separate columns.  The a's, b's, etc. don't have to line up so that each letter is in the "correct" column.  They just need to be broken out into separate columns.

I'm doing this in Python.  I'm open to using other libraries like Pandas.  There will be other columns included, not just two.  I made a simple example.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From pandas `str.split`

```
df=pd.concat([df,df.Info.str.split(',',expand=True)],1)
df
Out[611]: 
   Name        Info  0   1   2     3
0  Mike  a, b, c, d  a   b   c     d
1   Joe     a, f, z  a   f   z  None
```

Comment: To handle whitespaces: `'\s*,\s*'`

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ great :-)

Comment: this works great, but there is just one issue.  This leaves the original column in the results.  so I have "a, b, c" in one column and then the letters in their own columns.  How do I exclude the original column from the output?

Comment: @EricShreve  add drop at the end `df=pd.concat([df,df.Info.str.split(',',expand=True)],1).drop('Info',1)`

Answer (score 5):

IIUC:

```
df.assign(**df['Info'].str.split(',', expand=True).add_prefix('Info_'))
```

Output:

```
   Name        Info Info_0 Info_1 Info_2 Info_3
0  Mike  a, b, c, d      a      b      c      d
1   Joe     a, f, z      a      f      z   None
```

Note: You can also use `join` instead of `assign` (Using [@coldspeed \s*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47894861/python-separate-text-into-different-column-with-comma/47894906#comment82756631_47894906) to elimate spaces):

```
df.join(df['Info'].str.split('\s*,\s*', expand=True).add_prefix('Info_'))
```