# Convert xlsx to csv without merging the columns - Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, xlsx

I am trying to convert a 4-columns xlsx to csv, retaining the 4-columns format.
Every solution I tried (csv and pandas modules) keeps merging the 4 columns into 1, separating them with ',' (or any separator I choose).
Is there any way to write into separated columns?

Thank you in advance

Edit:
Example of my xlsx

```
number1   number11   name1   name11
number2   number22   name2   name22
...       
number(n) number(nn) name(n) name(nn)
```

With the answers I tried I get:

```
number1,number11,name1,name11
number2,number22,name2,name22
....
number(n),numer(nn),name(n),name(nn)
```

I want to keep the 4-column format just like if I write it on excel and save it .csv(comma seperated)

The blocks of code I have tried:

csv:

```
import csv
def to_csv(ws, csvname):
    with open(csvname, 'w', newline="") as f:
        c = csv.writer(f, dialect=csv.excel)
        for r in ws.rows:
            c.writerow([cell.value for cell in r])
```

pandas:

```
import pandas
def pd_to_csv(file):
    data_xls = pd.read_excel(file, index_col=None, encoding='iso8859_7')
    data_xls.to_csv(str(name[0:-5]) + '.csv', index=False, 
                    encoding='iso8859_7')
```

Comment: try using the separator `\t`

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Can you post your `.xlsx` file?

Comment: It is not merging 4 columns into 1. `CSV` by definition is `comma separated values`. When you save `CSV` data in file with `.csv` extension and open your `.csv` in a excel, it will show you four columns.

Comment: @Joe I already tried '\t' but it does not work.

Comment: @akshat I know, but I need to keep the 4 column or the file is not accepted. And actually it does merge them. When I open the file with Excel only column A has context.

Comment: @Drakumel In the menu of Excel you should go to `Data`-> `Text to column` and expand the cells from there

Comment: @Joe Oh, thank you. That could help. May you know if there is a python code that does the trick?

Comment: @Drakumel check if this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47894861/python-separate-text-into-different-column-with-comma

Comment: I finally made it by changing the separator to what excel identifies as csv delimiter ( ';' in my case). Thank you so much guys.